# Orchard CMS - query lists from views

Tags: orchardcms

I created a list and added some items to it. From a view ( not related to this list), I am trying to access the items of this list.

I can get the list of items by using the following query :

```
contentManager.Query<ContentPart>("myContentTypeName")
```

This gives me a list.

But, consider this scenario -

-> I create an myContentTypeName and add it to a list.

-> I create another Item but didn't add it to any list.

The above query returns ALL the items of that type. How can I filter this query and get only the items that are a part of the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using >= 1.4 version of Orchard, use the projector module. Starting with 1.4 List is pretty much deprecated. If you still need to use the List, I think what you want to do is query for the List content items, not the items within it.

Comment: Wouldn't you query content type that you had created? How would you determine if that is a part of the list or not?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it looks like you want to query using the CommonPart.Container.Id == {List.Id}. This might help: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/280709

Comment: Right. I ended up querying my contenttype and joining the query to     .Join<CommonPartRecord>().Where(cr => cr.Container != null)